# First order logic resolution algorithm . Ask with a negative request

Tags: first-order-logic

I try to ask a knowledge base with a negative request. So before the resolution the complement (positif here) is add to the set of clauses uses by the algorithm.

With these facts:

```
 Spouse(Sarah,Andrew)
 Spouse(Sophie,Edward)
```

And theses axioms :

```
(∀ [a , b , c ] (  (  ( Spouse(a,c) ∧ Spouse(b,c) )  ⇒ Egal(a,b) ) ))
this axiom mean onely two people can be spouse
(∀ [a , b ] (  ( Spouse(a,b) ⇔ Spouse(b,a) )  ))
(∀ [x ] ( Egal(x,x) ))
(∀ [x , y ] (  ( Egal(x,y) ⇒ Egal(y,x) )  ))
reverse
(∀ [x , y , z ] (  (  ( Egal(x,y) ∧ Egal(y,z) )  ⇒ Egal(x,z) )  ))
transitive
(∀ [x ] (  ( Egal(x,x) ⇒ Egal(x,x) )  ))
```

clauses turn into CNF

```
  (  (  ¬ Spouse(a0,c0)  ∨  ¬ Spouse(b0,c0)  )  ∨ Egal(a0,b0) ) 
  (  ¬ Spouse(a1,b1)  ∨ Spouse(b1,a1) ) 
  (  ¬ Spouse(b2,a2)  ∨ Spouse(a2,b2) ) 
 Egal(x0,x0)
  (  ¬ Egal(x1,y0)  ∨ Egal(y0,x1) ) 
  (  (  ¬ Egal(x2,y1)  ∨  ¬ Egal(y1,z0)  )  ∨ Egal(x2,z0) ) 
  (  ¬ Egal(x3,x3)  ∨ Egal(x3,x3) )
```

I can request

Spouse(Sarah,Andrew) or Spouse(Sophie,Edward)

this request ¬Spouse(Sarah,Edward) : is Sarah not spouse with Edward, doesn't work.

Of course I can ask if Spouse(Sarah,Edward) : is Sarah spouse with Edward, get no answer et consider that it's false.

What's wrong with this kind of request, because I don't know if there is a bug into my implementation or if it is not possible to do that (it's suppose to ...).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you mean that your problem is with the query `¬Spouse(Sarah,Edward)` instead of `¬Egal(Sarah,Edward)`? If you want to axiomatize equality, your theory is not complete.

Comment: sorry yes it was ¬Spouse(Sarah,Edward) instead of ¬Egal(Sarah,Edward). apparently I need axioms for every predicate and functions. Or I should use another technics like demodulation or paramodulation.

Comment: There is a model for your axioms and `Spouse(Sarah, Edward)` where `Egal(Sarah,Sophie)` holds. You need to add an axiom that Sarah is not equal to Sophie.

Comment: Thank you I undesrtand now, I thought that the axiom                                     (∀ [a , b , c ] (  (  ( Spouse(a,c) ∧ Spouse(b,c) )  ⇒ Egal(a,b) ) ))            was enough, but you're right there is nothing to allow to infer thatsomeone is not egal to someone else. But I have to add the fact NOT Egal(x,y) for every combinaison of people and it's absolutely not efficient I guess :)